# Jenkins with "agent none" on pipeline stage fails

Tags: windows, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've got a declarative pipeline, running on some windows Jenkins nodes:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'windows' }
    stages {
        stage('Build'){
            matrix {
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'COMPILER'
                        values 'gcc'
                    }
                    axis {
                        name 'FLAVOUR'
                        values 'debug', 'release'
                    }
                }
                stages {
                    stage('build') {
                        agent { label 'windows' }
                        steps {
                            bat '''
                                rem some build commands
                            '''
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is working fine. With the one caveat, that it uses 3 agents to build, 2 for the actual build and one for the top-level pipeline.

Exchanging the pipeline level agent statement by `agent none` resulted in the message:

```
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Any ideas, how to get rid of the need for the 3rd agent?